# Feasibility of me running a whole party in 1 on 1 campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, one-on-one

I love making characters. Even though I'm only in one campaign I have a whole host of character sheets just waiting to be played and the hardest part of DnD for me is only be able to play one character. So I had the idea that I could play 4 different characters in a 1 on 1 campaign with a DM. Naturally, I hit up my friend who DM's for the campaign I am currently in, and asked him what he thought of that idea. He said that nobody would DM for that and it doesn't sound very fun. I have a few questions regarding this:

- Is it at all realistic for me to play 4 characters at once?
- Can I expect to be able to find a DM willing to do this for me?
- I believe it will be fun, but is this indicative of a part of DnD I enjoy most,  that might translate better into another activity?

Comment: Right now, it's very difficult to assess this question; I feel it's either too broad, too opinion based, or too-<something else>. Regarding your first question, it might help to have specific details regarding what you intend to play, what pitfalls you anticipate, and how you would mitigate them. The second question is entirely dependent on your circle of friends/ability to meet people. Your third question is a matter of opinion, what's fun for some folks isn't for others; especially when you're inquiring about 'another activity'.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the other questions tagged with [tag:one-on-one], perhaps especially: [Is two-person D&D feasible for any edition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152442/52137) and [Is playing D&D 5e with two people feasible, particularly with the Starter Set adventure?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59430/52137)

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Are you interested in the *game* aspects of D&D, or the *role-playing* side?  Makes a HUGE difference to questions like this.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I love writing backstories for characters, but I'm not satisfied with just a backstory until I have a character that is playable and seems like it would be fun. In a campaign I like the game aspects more, I would say

Comment: Try Googling "D&D duet." I ran a duet campaign for a while where the other player had a five person party, some full PCs and some sidekicks that the player controlled in combat. It was a lot of fun. As a warning, the game moves much faster with only one player making decisions. It was a struggle at times for me as the DM to keep enough prepared.

Comment: Also worth noting that back in the day often all players controlled several characters. You might have 5 players and 16 characters in one group!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Depends on who you ask

Honestly, if this is going to be fun or not is entirely opinion based. Likewise, if you'll be able to find a DM to run it for you is also something we can't tell you. I could most likely find a DM who's okay with me running 100+ characters if I look long enough, but that doesn't help anybody.

**The real question is: Is it feasible?**

And I think that while it is certainly possible, I don't think this is going to result in the same type of campaign. From a combat perspective, it's really no big deal, you'll be able to make it work just fine, it might even go faster than normal because only two people are involved in the entire game.

However, in terms of social interactions, you'll obviously have the problem of literally being by yourself in the party. This will make intra-party roleplay rather awkward, as you're representing all sides of the conflict.

So it's certainly possible, and it might even work better in combat, but it's not going to result in the same type of back-and-forth roleplay as you'd normally get in a campaign. You run the risk of the DM feeling like he's watching you write a story whenever characters start discussing anything, which is most likely what your usual DM described as 'sounds boring'.

**My suggestion:**

Normally I'd suggest that perhaps D&D 5e isn't the type of game for you, but I honestly can't come up with any roleplays  where one player plays an entire party of adventurers, and I assume part of what you like about character creation is the 5e character creation

What might work better for you is this: *Oneshots*. Instead of trying to play four characters at once in a campaign, you play one of the many characters you want to play. But you play them for a game, and then the next game you play a different character if you want to try that one out.

*Oneshots are a great way for trying out new characters.*

Comment: Thank you! I like this idea because it sounds like it will give me a chance to explore the characters I create to my satisfaction without being beyond my abilities.

Comment: I think you mean "intra-party roleplay" (within the party) rather than "inter-party roleplay" (between multiple parties)

Comment: @StevenJackson That I do, I've fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So...

> Is it at all realistic for me to play 4 characters at once?

It is realistic for a single person to play multuple characters at once, especially with enough preparation. 
Sentient magical weapons, while not a D&D player character (usually?) are another type of literary character in a plot --having motivations, flaws, specialities, and weaknesses.  The level of preparation it takes to play another character grows with the number, quality, and intensity with which ot is portrayed.

> Can I expect to be able to find a DM willing to do this for me?

I can't factually answer the question; however, some people will try anything once. If you cannot find a DM, locally, at a game store, online forum, etc, I can recommend the Mythic GM Emulator as a system for solo play.  You could be your own gm and have ALL the characters, an entire UNIVERSE, no, a MULTIVERSE, AN OMNIVERSE OF CHARACTERS. YOU COULD GO MAD WITH CREATIVE POWER!

> I believe it will be fun, but is this indicative of a part of DnD I enjoy most, that might translate better into another activity?

Yes. This is indicative of wanting to be a gm, an author, a game director, or possibly a playright or play-actor.  This is personal experience. I make characters for fun.  I don't aim to min-max, but rather create sub-optimal characters who are invested in a goal. I also like to write stories or come up with twists on classical character tropes that may be interesting to see interact with others.

I say this also because a GM has to make an entire cast of characters, which never 'feels' bad for me, but is actually rather enjoyable. You can make as many characters as you want, but there are obviously other concerns you must attend to if you want to have players continue and enjoy your game.

If you arent looking to start GM experience, you may want to investigate "Troupe style play". A quick search on google pulled up references to a game called Ars Magica which may have more advice for you.

Sources: 
Weapons as characters: The adventure zone podcast characters Duck Newton - a park ranger and Beacon, his talking magical sword.

[...]Find a DM willing[...]? Sourceless, personal outlook.

[...]Indicative [of another activity]? Self.

[posted on mobile, will edit later for appearance, or you can edit, if you would like!]